# FreeDOS AUTOEXEC.BAT

Tags: batch-file, freedos

I am using a FreeDOS floppy boot disk made from `sys.com` of FreeDOS (I am using them on virtual box and floppy disk is virtual).

I have wasted all my day trying to make an `AUTOEXEC.BAT` which loads *ctmouse* (an app for using a mouse on FreeDOS), and *HIMEMX* (High Memory Manager).

With *ctmouse*, I just use

```
lh A:\folder\CTMOUSE.EXE
```

which works perfectly, while

```
DEVICE=A:\HIMEMX.EXE
```

does not work. It gives the error:

```
Bad command or filename -'DEVICE'.
```

Could anybody help? I have tried several things to solve this problem, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### FreeDOS boot disk configuration

`DEVICE=`commands belong in `config.sys`not `autoexec.bat`.

> **DEVICE**
>
> Usage:  `device=[d:][path]file [options]`
>
> Load the device driver specified by d:path\file (into conventional
>   [low 640KB] memory).
>
> The options are for the driver itself; refer to documentation that
>   came with your particular device for supported options and their
>   usage.
>
> e.g.  `device=himem.sys`

Source [Config.sys Options](http://www.freedos.org/kernel/config.txt)

---

#### How do I load `ctmouse`, like `autoexec.bat`? `lh` is not a `config.sys` command

Application such as `ctmouse` can still be loaded in `autoexec.bat`.

> **Examples**:
>
> IN A .BAT FILE / AUTOEXEC.BAT:
>
> `lh C:\fdos\bin\mkeyb.exe`
>
> `lh C:\fdos\bin\ctmouse.exe`

Source [Command: autoexec.bat](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/batch/autoexec.htm)